# How do I set up an installation script including ODBC-connection?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, odbc

Easy question this time.... I have a installation file, and a registry edit in my script.

How do I set up a ODBC-connection as well, actually I need to script up 2 ODBC-connections.

Any advice for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System ODBC settings are stored in the registry under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ODBC

I would suggest configuring the ODBC connections manually then exporting the registry values.  You can then either script a registry merge or write the values explicitly.  Remember to install the relevant drivers and associated ODBC registry settings for those as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Does anyone have any examples of doing it?

Comment: I was looking for the same answer and found this: https://www.itninja.com/question/script-to-setup-odbc-connections